# How do I solve this cube?

Tags: knowledge, visual, rubiks-cube

I’m trying to learn the cube but I'm stuck. How can I solve this in the least number of moves?

[image: front]

[image: posterior]

The answer is a phrase. Since it’s a secret phrase, an abbreviation will do.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Took a bit of time to assemble a cube with that pattern, but it can be solved:

> In just <s>five</s> four moves.
>
>  The book in the images is "The Simple Solution to Rubik's Cube" by James G. Nourse, which uses its own notation for moves, so we'll use that here.
>
>  Calling green side **T**op and the yellow side **F**ront, the shortest solution is:
>  R+, T+, F+, R+, L-
>  (In the more common Singmaster notation, this would be R, U, F, R, L')
>
>  But that's *five* moves I hear you saying.
>  Well, yes it is, but if we replace the final pair of moves (R+, L-) with an equivalent twist of the **M**iddle slice between them, we end up with a shorter solution of:
>  **R**+ **T**+ **F**+ **M**
>
>  Which is clearly telling you how to solve your cube by Reading The Fine Manual that is sitting underneath it.

Comment: Ah you got the last bit! I couldn't quite figure it out!

Comment: 'Fine' - haha :) Very politely done...

Comment: Haha, perfect solution.

Comment: @Stiv I'd prefer 'Fun'

Answer (score 3):

Based on the sides we can see, I believe this is the configuration of the cube

> [image: Rubik's config]

The least amount of solves required is:

> R U F R L' (according to https://rubiks-cube-solver.com/ because I'm not good enough to work it out by myself yet)

Comment: Regarding the notation you should have a closer look at the manual.